# Flatten dataframe to a single row

Tags: python, pandas

I'm have some hard to convert this table below to a single row.

[image]

The table I want to achieve is this one:

[image]

So far, I was able to get this with the code below.

[image]

```
df_hours = df.pivot(columns='DayID', values='StartTime')
```

But, as you can see, the SiteID remains in all rows. What I need now, is to keep it in a single row only. Any ideas?

Comment: what happens if you do `df.pivot(index='SiteID', columns='DayID', values='StartTime')`?

Comment: @Yuca that's gonna throw an error on duplicate axis something...

Comment: Read Q/A #10 in the dup link. Please be aware that duplicate column name should be avoided.

Comment: I don't think this question is duplicated, and the solutions from #10 could not help me with that...

Comment: This is the second time that someone throws a "duplicated question", and the second time I don't find the answer for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

As the DayID column is not unique... so try this;

```
df1["key"] = range(0,df1.shape[0])
df1["DayID"] = df1["DayID"].astype(str) + df1["key"].astype(str)
df2 = df1.pivot_table(index='SiteID', columns='DayID', values='StartTime')
df2.columns = ["".join(x for x in str1 if x.isalpha()) + "StartTime" for str1 in df2.columns]
```

Hope this Helps...

Comment: Unfortunately, I does not works. The values are not shown

Comment: # Apologies.. I didn't notice that DayID is not unique... Edited the code.. check now... if u've already solved then ignore... Thanks..

Comment: Hey man! Not sure I follow.. The "df1" should be the "df" dataframe?

Comment: yes.. correct! df1 is the raw data-frame before pivoting...